# PowerBI- Student Attendance

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

This might be a little hard to do or explain but basically I have some data with student attendance. I want to be able to only show a list of the students who have more then 10 absences. I will provide a sample of what my data looks like below. I'm new to PowerBI

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Is it `Attendance_codeid` unique to each attendance of a student? Are you familiar with a Table visual?

Comment: No, the only unique thing for each student would be the student_number